# how to setup and use openGL?

Tags: c++, opengl, mingw

I use mingW for compiling c++ code.  I want to make graphics using openGL. I use notepad++ for writing code. So how can I use the libraries of openGL?

Comment: You include gl/gl.h for start. If you need more take a look at glut or glew.

Comment: Try searching the internet for something like an "OpenGL tutorial". Though I think for someone with no experience in the matter, it is a bit premature to decide that OpenGL has to be your library of choice. There are much simpler, higher-level, portable frameworks available that let you get started with graphics much more efficiently.

Comment: Which tutorials have you looked at that you're having trouble with? Can you link to a website with an example you don't understand?

Comment: @EvanDark : why should I do that if I don't have openGL ?

Comment: Obviously, you have to have the openGL libraries.  http://www.transmissionzero.co.uk/computing/using-glut-with-mingw/  Once you have the libraries, it's no different than any other include done in C++.

Comment: @user1118321 : I just looked at this site: http://www.opengl.org/sdk/libs/GLee/ but in the readme file it says I have to do things with visual c++, but I don't have this

Comment: @Dale I used the link you gave and I did everything I had to do and when I want to compile it using the same commands as in the link, it says: GL/glut.h no such file or directory. What do I have to do now?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In MinGW you don't have to setup OpenGL. Already there is OpenGL library in a directory C:\~\MinGW\include\GL.Just include the GL/gl.h and GL/glu.h and write code for your OpenGL project.But if you are looking GLUT,GLFW,glew or other library then using the IDE is better soluton like code::blocks or visual studio then do google to setup these library for your IDE.

Answer (score 0):

Once you've got your OpenGL projects compiling and are maybe wondering what do do next, NeHe has a series of great OpenGL tutorials: http://nehe.gamedev.net/

From memory, they are all related to immediate mode (pre v3.0), but a good place to start - especially if you'd rather not use other libraries like GLUT for licensing reasons.

There is a also good list of tutorials here:

http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Getting_Started#Tutorials_and_How_To_Guides

By the way, you can download the Express edition of Visual C++, which is free.  Just in case you're only avoiding the Microsoft compiler because of cost:  http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/en-us/products/2010-editions/express

It's just a cut-back version of the professional edition.  Basically it doesn't have OpenMP, MFC or ATL, some more advanced debugging tools, and won't compile 64-bit apps.  But otherwise it's great.  The only thing I'd be upset about not having is 64-bit and OpenMP.  But it's free!  Feature comparison is here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hs24szh9.aspx

Answer (score 0):

**OpenGL Text Editor/No IDE Friendly**

After you write a .cpp files in Notepad,Notepad++,VS Code,Vim,Etc.

You can compile the .cpp file and generate a executable using MinGW on command line with the following command.

```
g++ ./main.cpp -o./main
```

Linking all the Opengl Project's files and libraries can quickly turn command line into looking like this

```
g++ /path/main.cpp /path/another.cpp... -I/path/includedlibirary... -L/path/headers... -lglfw3 -lopengl32 -lglu32 -lgdi32 -o/path/output_executable
```

[IMG:What it what eventually looks like in command line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OEg6W.png)

Instead of typing a similar monstrosity before every compile

I would use a Makefile and add it in the same directory as your project.Then compile the Makefile with following command.

```
mingw32-make
```

A Makefile

- Acts like a Batch script
- Acts like a linker in Codeblocks or Visual Studio: linking files and libraries to compiler
- Can tell the compiler where to output the executable .exe

[IMG:Example of OpenGL Project Directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l9Dc3.png)

Note: File paths are based on my setup and project's setup

Example Makefile:

```
    # Created Libraries directory in C: to store downloaded libraries 
    glfw_include = C:\Libraries\GLFW\include
    glfw_lib = C:\Libraries\GLFW\lib
    
    glad_include = C:\Libraries\GLAD\include
    glad_src =  C:\Libraries\GLAD\src\glad.c
    
    stb_include = C:\Libraries\STB\include
    stb_src = C:\Libraries\STB\src\stb.cpp
    
    glm_include = C:\Libraries\GLM\include
    
    json_include = C:\Libraries\JSON\include
    

    # Project's local header files
    local_include = ./Header
    # Project's local cpp files
    local_src = ./Source/shaders_class.cpp ./Source/textures_class.cpp ./Source/camera_class.cpp ./Source/meshes_class.cpp ./Source/model_class.cpp ./Source/shaders_EBO.cpp ./Source/shaders_VAO.cpp ./Source/shaders_VBO.cpp
    
    
    
    ################################################################################################################################################################################################################################
    
    
    CXX = g++
    CPP = ./Source/main.cpp
    TARGET = ./Bin/main
    
    
    OBJECTS = $(CPP) $(glad_src) $(stb_src) $(local_src)
    INCLUDES = -I$(glfw_include) -I$(glad_include) -I$(stb_include) -I$(glm_include) -I$(json_include) -I$(local_include) 
    LIBRARIES = -L$(glfw_lib)
    
    
    C_FLAGS = $(INCLUDES)
    LD_FLAGS = $(LIBRARIES) -lglfw3 -lopengl32 -lglu32 -lgdi32
    
    
    $(TARGET): $(CPP) # Final Output
    # Puts everything together in string that auto runs on command line
    # '''Ex: g++ <cpp files> -I<included> -L<header_files> -lglfw3 -lopengl32 -lglu32 -lgdi32 -o<output executable>'''
        $(CXX) $(OBJECTS) $(C_FLAGS) $(LD_FLAGS) -o$(TARGET)
```

Example output from Makefile

```
g++ ./Source/main.cpp C:\Libraries\GLAD\src\glad.c C:\Libraries\STB\src\stb.cpp ./Source/shaders_class.cpp ./Source/textures_class.cpp ./Source/camera_class.cpp ./Source/meshes_class.cpp ./Source/model_class.cpp ./Source/shaders_EBO.cpp ./Source/shaders_VAO.cpp ./Source/shaders_VBO.cpp -IC:\Libraries\GLFW\include -IC:\Libraries\GLAD\include -IC:\Libraries\STB\include -IC:\Libraries\GLM\include -IC:\Libraries\JSON\include -I./Header  -LC:\Libraries\GLFW\lib -lglfw3 -lopengl32 -lglu32 -lgdi32 -o./Bin/main
```

**Credit To:**

**Recommend for linking files to MinGW / Creating Makefile**

- Sonars Systems: SDL 2 Tutorial 1c [SETUP] Windows and MinGW Setup
  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ybYMOKEW9IY&t=15s

**Recommend OpenGL Intro**

- Victor Gordan: OpenGL Tutorials
  https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLPaoO-vpZnumdcb4tZc4x5Q-v7CkrQ6M-

Comment: Hi @defineace, welcome to SO. Glad you're a new contributor. Instead of posting a list of links, it's best to incorporate the key points into your answer (with appropriate attribution), as links may go dead. Also, it's not clear what this makefile has to do with the question at hand- it's very unlikely the OP's setup will match the paths in that file.

Comment: Hi @irowe, Thank you for your feedback, very much appreciated. I added why I used a Makefile. Also added image of project's directory to reference with MakeFile. Thanks :)